# How to have background-image and gradient background-color work on one selector in CSS?

Tags: html, css, webkit, scrollbar, background-color

I'm trying to style scrollbars in Webkit and here's the code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #424242 1%,#383838 100%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Now, apart from making this scrollbar have round corners and gradient, I would also like to put little dots in the middle of it - you know, the ones scrollbars usually have so that it's easy to identify them as draggable scrollbars. Problem is, if I add these properties:

```
background-image: url("../images/scrollbar_dots.png");
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

the browser starts ignoring the previous ones and my scrollbar becomes transparent. I, obviously, can't just put a div inside and make it have this background with dots, because a scrollbar is a pseudo element. Any ideas how to make it work? (Javascript would do, but I don't even know how to get scrollbars from DOM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate them using a comma, as gradients are nothing but background images, so you can use multiple background images by separating them using a comma...

```
background: url(#), YOUR_GRADIENT_CODE_HERE;
              ----^----
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tGqtg/)

Comment: @snitko See my demo, you need to use `background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;` <--- like this, same goes for `background-position` as well

Comment: Perfect, that worked. Easier than I thought. Thank you very much.